# IE 7/8 Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Hi i hope you can help me

I am having an issue in IE 7/8 with the rock solid template. See the template http://www.pixelsparadise.com/showcase_2013/#load=http://www.rocksolid.joomlatemplates.info

It seems to be caused by JavaScript code in the header.

The error code i receive in the IE debugger is

```
SCRIPT1014: Invalid character 

<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("sectors").addEventListener('change', function () {
    window.location = this.value;},false); ​</script>
```

This is the piece of code seemingly causing the problem.

Basically the area stops any button used within the template from working. Any ideas how to fix this for Internet Explorer 7/8?

Thanks

Comment: Apologies i have seemed to have sorted it myself. Because i was trying to link around a <button> rather then using <a href it was causing these issues in IE.

Comment: This code can't work on IE<9 anyhow: `addEventListener` wasn't supported prior to IE9. Look into `attachEvent` for old IE

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra, "invisible" (it can be seen if you copy that code into something like Notepad++) character just before the `</script>` tag; just delete everything between the `;` and `</script>` and it should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

take out the space in the script tag closure

```
​</script>
```

change to

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("sectors").addEventListener('change', function () {
    window.location = this.value;},false); </script>
```